# When creating global struct variable for linked list it says illegal initialization otherwise it works fine

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have created this structure and I am trying to perform the basic operations with the help of functions which I created. My program works but I  have to declare the `temp` variable inside every function. I tried making it global but it says "**illegal initialization**".

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head=NULL;
struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

//If I remove the above line and move it to the disp function it works    
//but in this case it says illegal initialization

void disp()
{
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Should I add the whole program to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the global variables are initialized by compiler and hence it must be a constant value like NULL in the first line. But in your case, you are trying to call a function (malloc()) which is not allowed.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialization-global-static-variables-c/